# Check-boxes for multi screen size compatability

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-view, android-checkbox

I'm trying to create a layout that has a background (shown below) and have 10 check boxes (2 columns of 5 rows) in the white area.  I can make this work via trial and error for one size view but how would i get this to keep the same aspect ratios for different screen sizes?

I'm open to any ideas, whether it's multiple layouts for different sizes or something more clever.

[image]

Comment: Basically did you know anything about hdpi, mdpi, ldpi?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9891065/android-scale-image-keeping-its-aspect-ratio-in-background-drawable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you want to build a table of checkboxes (and associated text labels, I assume), I would suggest you use [TableLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html).

Comment: But will this layout fit to the size of the white box for different screen sizes?

Comment: Yes it will, if you set your columns as stretchable. You should really take an hour to make a prototype.

Answer (score 1):

Basically wrap your check boxes with `LinearLayout` and don't give hard coded values for

```
android:layout_width=""

android:layout_height=""
```

If you can't, my answer will change. Also `TableLayout` another approach for your work.