# how to crop a Bitmap so it matches the screen size

Tags: android, bitmap

Starting point: in my app I let the user pick an image that will be used as the app's background. In case the image's width/height is larger than the device's screen width/height, I want to crop the image so it matches the device dimensions (see picture below).

[image]

I tried the method below, but with no luck at all, the resulting image is messed up.

```
    private Bitmap crop(Bitmap bmp) {
    int centerW = bmp.getWidth() / 2;
    int centerH = bmp.getHeight() / 2;
    int startX = centerW
            //returns screen width
            - GetSettings.getScreenDimensions(getActivity())[0] / 2;
    int startY = centerH
            //returns screen height
            - GetSettings.getScreenDimensions(getActivity())[1] / 2;

    return Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, startX, startY,
            GetSettings.getScreenDimensions(getActivity())[0],
            GetSettings.getScreenDimensions(getActivity())[1]);

}
```

I guess I'm misunderstanding the parameters I need to pass to the `createBitmap()` method to get a proper result.

**So how can I crop a `Bitmap` to make it's width/height to match the screen's width/height?**

Comment: This should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9891929/2664466

Comment: What do you mean by "the resulting image is messed up" ? Also as Collin mention, you might need to fit the resulting bitmap in your ImageView

Comment: @Chewie it means that the result is just some blurred piece of the original image. I don't use any Views at this point, I create a directory on sd card and save the image there

Answer (score 2):

I'm not an android developer, but I would imagine your startX and startY variables are incorrect.

I would think you would want something like this:

```
startX = (bmp.getWidth() - screenWidth) / 2;
startY = (bmp.getHeight() - screenHeight) / 2;
```

Then your draw X and Y lengths would just be the screen width and height.

Comment: looks logical but still the resulting image is just some blurred piece of the original image..